# Small subgroups of $GL_n$ and Lie algebras

Tags: linear-algebra, lie-groups, lie-algebras

Working on Lie algebra basics, I found the following property: let $G$ be a closed subgroup of $GL_n$ over $\mathbb{R}$. Let $\mathfrak{g}$ its Lie algebra and $\mathfrak{m}$ a supplementary space.  Then

> There is a neighborhood $V$ of $0$ in $\mathfrak{m}$ such that $\exp(V) \cap G = \{I_n\}$.

I have the feeling that this could lead to prove the usual property stating that $GL_n$ has no arbitrarily small subgroups. Is it possible? (or is it totally unrelated?)

Comment: What does "small" mean? It has a two-element subgroup, for example, $\{\pm I\}$.

Comment: What do you mean by *supplementary space*?

Comment: @Conifold Small in any norm-sense, containing an arbitrarily small neighbourhood

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I guess I mean "whose direct sum with g is the whole space M_n(R)"

Comment: Meaning, contained in a sufficiently small neighborhood of $I$?

Comment: It's hard to say more if you don't say more about your intuitive proof.